# Rearrange Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I banging my head from last 3 hours to rearrange a array, so far no luck.

I need this array to be rearrange like this: Array (A)

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [langtext] => hello world
        [mainlang] => hello world
        [lang] => en
        [prefix] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [langtext] => Bonjour le monde
        [mainlang] => hello world
        [lang] => fr
        [prefix] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [langtext] => Привет мир
        [mainlang] => hello world
        [lang] => ru
        [prefix] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [langtext] => provide
        [mainlang] => provide
        [lang] => en
        [prefix] => 7
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [langtext] => обеспечить
        [mainlang] => provide
        [lang] => ru
        [prefix] => 7
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [langtext] => fournir
        [mainlang] => provide
        [lang] => fr
        [prefix] => 7
    )
)
```

Rearrange as: Array (B)

```
Array (
   [prefix] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [en] => hello world
                [mainlang] => hello world
                [fr] => Bonjour le monde
                [ru] => Привет мир

            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [en] => provide
                [mainlang] => provide
                [fr] => fournir
                [ru] => обеспечить
            )
 }
```

Detail:
I need to rearrange array from (A) to (B), "lang" key value are different in all array where "prefix" are same.

I tried foreach (but only able to return prefix as key and any "lang" value.

```
foreach (_allLangText() as $lang_array=>$key){

$lang_array_return['prefix']
[$lang_array['prefix']]=array($lang_array['lang']=>$lang_array['langtext']);
  }
```

And i get output like this, which is incorrect:

```
Array
   (
     [prefix] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [ru] => Привет мир
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [fr] => fournir
            )
 )
```

Finally, there is possibility that there is more "lang" value in array, I mean "en","ru","fr" or "de" etc. and if there is 4 different value in lang then same "prefix" will repeat in 4 arrays.

**VAR_Export:**

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'langtext' => 'hello world',
      'mainlang' => 'hello world',
      'lang' => 'en',
      'prefix' => '1',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'langtext' => 'Bonjour le monde',
      'mainlang' => 'hello world',
      'lang' => 'fr',
      'prefix' => '1',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'langtext' => 'Привет мир',
      'mainlang' => 'hello world',
      'lang' => 'ru',
      'prefix' => '1',
    ),
   3 => 
    array (
      'langtext' => 'provide',
      'mainlang' => 'provide',
      'lang' => 'en',
      'prefix' => '7',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'langtext' => 'обеспечить',
      'mainlang' => 'provide',
      'lang' => 'ru',
      'prefix' => '7',
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'langtext' => 'fournir',
      'mainlang' => 'provide',
      'lang' => 'fr',
      'prefix' => '7',
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Could you provide result of `var_export` instead of `var_dump`? It'll be easier to copy and implement into PHP :)

Comment: From a quick glance I think you want: `$lang_array_return['prefix']
[$lang_array['prefix']][$lang_array['lang']]=$lang_array['langtext']);` inside your foreach. At least it should get you a step closer to the desired result.

Comment: Is this a school homework it reads very similiar to other school homeworks on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek added the `var_export` result!

Comment: @Martin no! its not a school work, I am not that good with PHP but i am trying, give me a way to make this work, just let me know the methods, code are not required, i try if i failed i will ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that you reversed key and value in the `foreach` syntax. When you use `=>`, the key variable comes before it, and the value variable after. Any way, you don't need the key.

Secondly, by assigning one key/value pair (array) to your result structure, you can never get anything more than one key assigned in the end. Instead, you should assign to the nested key:

```
foreach (_allLangText() as $lang_array) {
    $lang_array_return["prefix"][$lang_array["prefix"]][$lang_array["lang"]] 
          = $lang_array["langtext"];
    $lang_array_return["prefix"][$lang_array["prefix"]]["mainlang"] 
          = $lang_array["mainlang"];
}
```

Comment: This solution is working, i was very closed but messaged up when i try to add "langtext" in "lang" by using array. (i hope i am not wrong) :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple: group elements by prefix and clear grouped elements living only translations.

Algorithm is simple:

1. For each element take its prefix and put it into `$output` if it doesn't exist yet.
2. Now check if in `$output[prefix]` there exist `mainlang` key- if doesn't add it with known value
3. Add the translation to the `$output[prefix][lang]` with known value

That's it.

Here you have working solution with example use:

```
$input = array(
        array(
            "langtext" => "hello world",
            "mainlang" => "hello world",
            "lang" => "en",
            "prefix" => 1,
        ),
        array(
            "langtext" => "Bonjour le monde",
            "mainlang" => "hello world",
            "lang" => "fr",
            "prefix" => 1,
        ),
        array(
            "langtext" => "Привет мир",
            "mainlang" => "hello world",
            "lang" => "ru",
            "prefix" => 1,
        ),
        array(
            "langtext" => "hello world",
            "mainlang" => "hello world",
            "lang" => "en",
            "prefix" => 1,
        ),
        array(
            "langtext" => "fournir",
            "mainlang" => "provide",
            "lang" => "fr",
            "prefix" => 7,
        ),
        array(
            "langtext" => "обеспечить",
            "mainlang" => "provide",
            "lang" => "ru",
            "prefix" => 7,
        )
    );

$output = array();

foreach($input as $translation){
    if(!array_key_exists($translation["prefix"], $output))
        $output[$translation["prefix"]] = array();

    if(!array_key_exists("mainlang", $output[$translation["prefix"]]))
        $output[$translation["prefix"]]["mainlang"] = $translation["mainlang"];

    $output[$translation["prefix"]][$translation["lang"]] = $translation["langtext"];
}
```

And now

```
var_dump($output);
```

results in:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["mainlang"]=>
    string(11) "hello world"
    ["en"]=>
    string(11) "hello world"
    ["fr"]=>
    string(16) "Bonjour le monde"
    ["ru"]=>
    string(19) "Привет мир"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    ["mainlang"]=>
    string(7) "provide"
    ["fr"]=>
    string(7) "fournir"
    ["ru"]=>
    string(20) "обеспечить"
  }
}
```

Comment: Explain your answer. How does it work. Why does it work?

Comment: It's rather simple I'd say. The problem is simple: Group the elements by prefix and reduce grouped elements living only translations. And so I do in the loop with additional checks to avoid errors

Comment: Updated my answer